# Connection Refused on AWS Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I have a linux AWS instance.  I am running the following script on it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

    #This script installs java, sbt and the application
    #Run this script on a new EC2 instance as the user-data script, which is run by `root` on machine start-up.
    sudo yum update -y

    sudo yum install -y docker

sudo service docker start

docker run repo/carrie
```

Everything installs and I get the below message in the logs:

```
REST interface bound to /0.0.0.0:8080
```

However when I try to actually access the port like so:

```
curl 0.0.0.0/8080
```

I get the below message:

```
Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8080: Connection refused
```

I have tried editing the inbound rules so that 8080 is open but it doesn't seem to work.  Maybe because I'm editing the rules after the instance has already launched?

Comment: curl from where? with-in the box or outside?

Comment: as root user from within the box(which I've ssh-ed into)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to publish the container's port to the host in the `docker run` command

```
$ docker run --help
...
-p, --publish list                   Publish a container's port(s) to the host
...
```

The last line of your script should look like this if the process in the container listens on port 80:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 repo/carrie
```

Comment: Just add `-p 8080:<port of process in container>` to your `docker run` command like in my answer.

Comment: great thank you - now I get this error! Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 80: Connection refused

Comment: Did you `curl localhost:8080`? Maybe the script command has to look like this: `docker run -p 8080:8080 repo/carrie`

Answer (score 0):

The container gets its own interface, hence host's 0.0.0.0 is not applicable.

Tell docker to bind container port 8080 out to the host:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 repo/carrie
```